# CSS is not loading in IE11 and Chrome

Tags: html, css

CSS used in my html page is

```
<style type="text/css"> 
body {background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Calibri;} 
table{margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;border:1px solid RoyalBlue;border-         collapse:collapse;font-size:90%;} 
td{margin:0px;border:1px solid RoyalBlue;padding:1px;} 
td.tcname_selected {{margin:0px;align:center;background-     color:LightSkyBlue;min-width:900px;color:white;font-weight:bold;} 
td.tcname {{margin:0px;align:center;background-color:LightSkyBlue;min- width:900px;} 
td.tccontainer {padding:0px;} 
tr.stepstbl_vis {} 
tr.stepstbl_notvis {display:none;padding:1px;border:0px;} 
<!-- table.stepstbl {margin:0px;border:none;padding:1px;} --> 
table.stepstbl {border:1px solid RoyalBlue;border-collapse:collapse;font- size:90%;} 
td.step_head {{margin:0px;align:center;background-  color:LightSkyBlue;border:1px solid RoyalBlue;padding:1px;} 
td.step_reg {{margin:0px;border:1px solid RoyalBlue;padding:1px} 
span.hidden {display:none;} 
</style> 

CSS is not loading when i use it in my code -
<body> 
<table width="90%" align="center"> 
<tr> 
<td width="97%" class="tcname" id="tsname1"> 
</td> 
</td> 
</tr>
```

Same code is working fine when i use it in IE8 browser.Table is getting created ,but it does not display the back ground color of table cell in blue as CSS is not loading in IE11 and Chrome.Can some one help me to find out the root cause?

Comment: format your css code .there are syntax errors .for example `border- collapse:collapse;`  see https://jsfiddle.net/rzx5t6p4/1/

Comment: To check CSS for errors, you can use the W3C validator: http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/ Note however, that it is not foolproof. In this case, it does not flag the HTML comment in the CSS.

Comment: That said, I don't really understand why you think that property names with spaces in them would be OK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a quick fix of your code, not sure about what you really want to get, but should work

```
<style type="text/css"> 
body {background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Calibri;} 
table {margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;border:1px solid RoyalBlue;border-collapse:collapse;font-size:90%;} 
td {margin:0px;border:1px solid RoyalBlue;padding:1px;} 
td.tcname_selected {margin:0px; text-align:center; background-color: LightSkyBlue;min-width:900px;color:white;font-weight:bold;} 
td.tcname {margin:0px; text-align:center;background-color:LightSkyBlue;min-width:900px;} 
td.tccontainer {padding:0px;} 
tr.stepstbl_vis {} 
tr.stepstbl_notvis {display:none;padding:1px;border:0px;} 
table.stepstbl {margin:0px;border:none;padding:1px;}
table.stepstbl {border:1px solid RoyalBlue;border-collapse:collapse;font-size:90%;} 
td.step_head {margin:0px; text-align:center; background-color:LightSkyBlue;border:1px solid RoyalBlue;padding:1px;} 
td.step_reg {margin:0px;border:1px solid RoyalBlue;padding:1px} 
span.hidden {display:none;} 
</style>

<body> 
<table width="90%" align="center"> 
<tr> 
<td width="97%" class="tcname" id="tsname1">cell 1</td> 
<td>cell 2</td> 
</tr>
```