# My CSS button and border style is working in IE11 but it's Not loading in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, jsp

I am using simple border and button CSS style in pages and it's working fine in IE11 browser. However it's not at all working in Google Chrome.

I am not sure if I'm doing any mistake.
I checked these links, but didn't get my solution.

[CSS button not working in Google Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097786/css-button-not-working-in-google-chrome)

[Why is hover working in IE11, but not in Chrome?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34649964/why-is-hover-working-in-ie11-but-not-in-chrome)

[CSS is not loading in IE11 and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33583014/css-is-not-loading-in-ie11-and-chrome)

Below code i used:

```
div .divisonOutsetStyle
{
    border-width: thin;
    border-style: inset;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border-color: #2F4F4F;
    padding: 2rem;
    spacing: 2rem;
}
```

and,

```
input[type="submit"],
input[type="button"]
{
    display: inline-block;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    test-decoration: none;
    height: 26px;
    font-size: 9PT;
    font-family: Century Gothic;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius: 25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    background:#4682B4;
    color: #ffffff;
    box-shadow: 6px 5px 24px #666666;
}
```

Also I linked CSS in jsp pages as:

```
<LINK REL="stylesheet" TYPE="text/css" HREF="application.css" media="all" >
```

In any way, Chrome is not showing the CSS styles, please suggest me to overcome this problem.

Comment: Can you provide code https://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Not what is causing you issues but `spacing` is not a CSS property. You also used `test-decoration` instead of `text-decoration`.

Comment: @BaliBalo Thanks,, I rectify those. But the problem still exists,the button and border style aren't loading in Chrome at all.

Comment: @Prosenjit It would make it a lot easier to help you if you included the HTML that you are trying to style - please see the documentation about [minimal reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)